# Questions regarding forms and php (clearing form, live refresh, multiline)

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, forms

I have several questions regarding forms and PHP but if I should put them into different posts then I will.

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="t-form" name="tForm" action="translate.php" method="POST">
            <div id="t-bar">
                <div class="t-select">
                    <select name="start-lang" id="choice-button">
                        <option value="english">English</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>into</label>
                    <select name="end-lang" id="choice-button" onChange="document.forms['tForm'].submit();">
                        <option value="caps"<?php if ($resLang == 'caps') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>CAPS</option>
                        <option value="lowercase"<?php if ($resLang == 'lowercase') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>lowercase</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" id="t-submit" value="Translate">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="t-main">
                        <textarea id="txt-source" name="t-src" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Type in what you would like to convert…" onChange="document.forms['tForm'].submit();"><?php echo $source; ?></textarea>
                        <input type="button" id="t-clear" onclick="this.form.elements['t-src'].value=''">

                        <textarea id="txt-result" name="txt-result" readonly disabled="disabled" placeholder="result..."><?php echo $result; ?></textarea>
                        <input type="button" id="t-copy" name="t-copy">
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Question 1:** I currently have `onclick="this.form.elements['t-src'].value=''"`  which clears one textbox when the button is pressed.  Is it possible to have the same attribute clear both textareas in my form? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere for clearing 2 elements with 1 button.  I do not want to clear the form as I would like to keep the selected dropdown values so that is why I'm doing it this way.
**Question 2:** How would I go about implementing a live refresh of the results textarea so they user can simply type and see the result?   I've look at the ajax and jquery required and am confused as most don't show how to output to a form element and only to a div.  (*Similar to google's translate*)

**Question 3:**  I realized that if a user does a new line in the textarea, when they submit for translate, it gives them a php header error.  Any ideas how I can avoid this?  This is my header for the translate.php file used in the form:

```
header("location: /?txt-result=$result&t-src=$textSource&end-lang=$outputLang");
```

I am merely trying to do this as a learning excersise and would really appreciate any guidance or answers to the three questions.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: for the third question, you will have to use urlencode($var) for each variable. The other two are more complicated. and in the first one, you write "I currently have .... which clears one textbox", some text missing there?

Comment: Thanks for the urlencode hint, worked like a charm!  Regarding question 1, I went ahead and fixed that, Thanks!

Comment: how do you want to identify the textboxes you want to clear? they should have a class of their owm? or you know their IDs???

Comment: The second question seems easy with what you have already; as you are already setting the value of form elements to `''`, use a similar statement to set the value of your form element to the return value of the ajax code you have found examples of. The only difference is that you are changing the value of the form element and they are changing the inner html of a ``div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1:** Have your `onclick` event call a function which clears those values for you:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function clearTextareas()
    {
        this.form.elements["t-src"].value = "";
        this.form.elements["txt-result"].value = "";
    }
</script>

<input type="button" id="t-clear" onclick="clearTextareas()">
```

**Answer 2:** Add an `onkeydown` event in the source textarea that peforms the translation (or whatever it needs to do) and then puts the result in the result textarea:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function translateText()
    {
        var text = this.form.elements["t-src"].value;
        // do something
        this.form.elements["txt-result"].value = text;
    }
</script>

<textarea id="txt-source" name="t-src" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Type in what you would like to convert…" onkeydown="translateText()"><?php echo $source; ?></textarea>
```

**Answer 3:** Perhaps an `onsubmit` event in the `form` element that will sanitize the input from the text area. Have a look at JavaScript's [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp). Perhaps this will work for you:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function sanitize()
    {
        this.form.elements["t-src"].value = encodeURIComponent(this.form.elements["t-src"].value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the clear answers! Answer 1 worked like a charm.  I didn't think about doing a function and including both calls so I will keep that in mind! /// Answer 2 works but causes a refresh.  I'll look more into Ajax and such so I don't have to refresh the page. /// Answer 3 I never heard of so I will go and read up on that. /// Again thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: The code I posted for answer 2 shouldn't cause a refresh. If the code you use to do the translation is located in some external server-side script (I assume PHP), then yes, you will need to use AJAX to call the script without refreshing, but you can make the AJAX call in the place where it says `// do something`. Definitely look into AJAX, as you will undoubtedly need it in future endeavors. I would even suggest either using a library or even writing your own in order to reduce the bulky amount of code needed to make the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

## question 1

you should have:

```
onclick="clearTextboxes();"
```

and in javascript something like:

```
//if you want to delete all the inputs that are of type text
function clearTextboxes(){
   var inputs = document.getElementById('t-form').getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var control in inputs){
      if(inputs[control].getAttribute('type') == 'text'){
         inputs[control].value = '';
      }
   }
}
```

## question 2

it is far too broad to put here as an answer, you should really look at jQuery's $.ajax, and create a different question with specific doubts.

## question 3

use the PHP urlencode() function